# Problems with multiple repeated symbols in Clapack

Tags: compiler-errors, lapack

I am trying to use my own dynamic library with Ctypes in Python. That library uses a function of Clapack that I tried to include in compilation of the dynamic library. First, It compiled without errors but when called from Python gives a error of missing Clapack function.

After some searchs in internet I compiled Clapack with -fPIC.

But now I am having another problem. The command to compile and linking is the following:

gcc -shared -O3 -fPIC my_code.c -o my_code.so -Wl,--whole-archive liblapack_LINUX.a libf2c.a libblas_LINUX.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive

and gives the following error:

/usr/bin/ld: libblas_LINUX.a(lsame.o): in function `lsame_': lsame.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of` lsame_'; liblapack_LINUX.a(lsame.o):lsame.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: libblas_LINUX.a(xerbla.o): in function `xerbla_': xerbla.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of` xerbla_'; liblapack_LINUX.a(xerbla.o):xerbla.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: libblas_LINUX.a(xerbla_array.o): in function `xerbla_array__': xerbla_array.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of` xerbla_array__'; liblapack_LINUX.a(xerbla_array.o):xerbla_array.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The following option is no longer supported in gcc: --allow-multiple-definition

Any help?

Thanks,

Luís Gonçalves

What I tried already explained in the post.

Comment: And adding -fcommon in compilation of Clapack and to the compilation command above does not change anything.

Comment: Solved by chatGPT with another/simpler approach.